# How do I avoid purchasing low quality monitors which exhibit these phenomena?

Tags: display

I have two monitors:
 1. 20" HP Compaq LE2002x
 2. 20" HP W2072a

The W2072a is of much lower quality. I have two particular complaints about the W2072a which are not exhibited by the LE2002x:

1. When viewing text, there appears to be a greenish color between the letters, particularly if the letters have lines that are close together, such as the letter m.
2. When viewing something dark, such as a black terminal window, there seems to be a grayish haze over it. On the LE2002x, however, it looks pitch black.

Do these phenomena have some particular name? Is there some metric in the technical specs which would help me avoid purchasing a monitor with these properties?

Comment: I don't know if this addresses your specific concerns, but in general you want to avoid TN monitors which is the [type of LCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Thin-film-transistor_liquid-crystal_display#Types). IPS are much better at colour reproduction, viewing angles, etc.

Comment: These both sound like setting issues. Is the HP monitor running at native resolution? Have you color calibrated it?